# Allowing cross-site requests between subdomains without changing file contents of second sub domain

Tags: javascript, iis, iframe, cors, xss

I am currently attempting to wrap a web application (ConnectWise) for inclusion within my company's central intranet site. It's a fairly simple process for the most part; create a containing page, with an iframe, point the iframe at the ConnectWise url. This part works for almost all of the functionality.

The problem comes during certain select features of the app (in this case, part of the process of creating a timesheet entry), which simply fail to work. Chrome gives the following console output.

`Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'frame' property from 'Window': Blocked a frame with origin "https://app.example.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://host.example.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.`

I am aware this is caused by the security options for cross-site and same-origin policies. Given the following points, is there a way to overcome this?

- I have **full control** over `https://host.example.com`

  - I **can** change html, javascript, and file contents
  - I **can** change IIS settings and headers
- I have **partial control** over `https://app.example.com`

  - I **can not** change html, javascript, and file contents
  - I **can** change IIS settings and headers.

I have tried setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` on each server, which so far is the only method I've come across that does not involve being able to change the file contents for the app server. This does not appear to work when given the settings (and combinations of settings) of

- `*` or `https://app.example.com` while on `https://host.example.com`
- `*` or `https://host.example.com` while on `https://app.example.com`

**Edit:**

The solution to [this "duplicate" question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame) is not applicable here. I **do not** have access to change file contents (including javascript) of the iframed page (`app.example.com`). Additionally, the script requiring the permission to run is the page within the iframe, not the page hosting the iframe.

Comment: See my answer posted at:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31232348/get-data-out-of-json-array-from-external-url/31237694#31237694][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31232348/get-data-out-of-json-array-from-external-url/31237694#31237694

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS headers such as `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` only affect AJAX requests, not DOM access.

However, If they are both on the same domain but different subdomains then you can include the following on each page:

```
document.domain = 'example.com';
```

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/domain):

> One document is allowed to access another if they have both set
>   document.domain to the same value, indicating their intent to
>   cooperate

If `app.example.com` has any `script` includes to `host.example.com` then you could put the above code in those scripts to set the domain.

e.g.

```
<script src="https://host.example.com/setup.js"></script>
```

Comment: This seems to be the way to go. While I cannot directly control any of the script on the "app" pages, I have discovered that I can inject it using the URL Rewrite module. 
This should work if I can find a reliable pattern to match against to ensure it's always injected. The app does not seem to follow common html standards. (I had thought that matching against `<head>` would be pretty sure-fire, but no.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible.

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` primarily affects getting raw data from HTTP requests, not live DOMs.

[`postMessage`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame) can let frames on different origins communicate, but it requires JS to be included on both pages.